# How to get Neighboring Cell Info in android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I am upgrading support of my application to Android Q but from updated SDK there is no such method like getNeighboringCellInfo() available in TelephonyManager class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html is there any way to get Neighboring Cell Info?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the official android/google documentation - `NeighboringCellInfo` class is deprecated

[image]

Comment: Agree, But there is no such method to get Neighboring Cell Info inside CellInfo class.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep `CellInfo` is an abstract class - it will be implemented by other framework classes such as `CellInfoGsm` or `CellInfoLte` etc. You may need to search inside those classes and check if any of those or their relative classes has an implementation of `getNeighboringCellInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

`getNeighboringCellInfo` is deprecated now, and it's replaced with `getAllCellInfo`.

This method returns a list of `List<CellInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after sdk 29, `getNeighboringCellInfo` is deprecated.
It's replaced with `getAllCellInfo`.

The usage example is as follow:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
     return cellInfoList;
}
cellInfoList = manager.getAllCellInfo();
if (cellInfoList != null && cellInfoList.size() > 0) {
     for (CellInfo info : cellInfoList) {
         //
     }
}
```

Also, there are other tool method to get param in `CellInfo`.
You can refer to them if you need.

```
public static int neighboringCellInfoGetLac(CellInfo cellInfo) {

    int lac = 0;
    try {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo;
                lac = cellInfoGsm.getCellIdentity().getLac();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                lac = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity().getTac();
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2
                    && cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                CellInfoWcdma cellInfoLte = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
                lac = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity().getLac();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                CellInfoCdma cellInfoCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfo;
                lac = cellInfoCdma.getCellIdentity().getNetworkId();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoTdscdma) {
                CellInfoTdscdma cellInfoTdscdma = (CellInfoTdscdma) cellInfo;
                lac = cellInfoTdscdma.getCellIdentity().getLac();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lac;
}

public static int neighboringCellInfoGetCid(CellInfo cellInfo) {

    int cid = 0;
    try {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo;
                cid = cellInfoGsm.getCellIdentity().getCid();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                cid = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity().getCi();
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2
                    && cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                CellInfoWcdma cellInfoLte = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
                cid = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity().getCid();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                CellInfoCdma cellInfoCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfo;
                cid = cellInfoCdma.getCellIdentity().getBasestationId();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoTdscdma) {
                CellInfoTdscdma cellInfoTdscdma = (CellInfoTdscdma) cellInfo;
                cid = cellInfoTdscdma.getCellIdentity().getCid();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cid;
}

public static int neighboringCellInfoGetRssi(CellInfo cellInfo) {

    int rssi = 0;
    try {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo;
                rssi = cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                rssi = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength().getRssi();
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2
                    && cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                CellInfoWcdma cellInfoLte = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
                rssi = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                CellInfoCdma cellInfoCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfo;
                rssi = cellInfoCdma.getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();
            } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoTdscdma) {
                CellInfoTdscdma cellInfoTdscdma = (CellInfoTdscdma) cellInfo;
                rssi = cellInfoTdscdma.getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rssi;
}
```